# how to set layout wrap scaled content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-image

my code is like below,when the FrameLayout layout_height from

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="120dp"
```

the layout becomes

[image]

i hope the image's height will become 120dp, and keep the scale. 
And the width of the layout will be followed by changes , as described wrap_content , 
but it only seems to adapt to the size of the original image .

what can i do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_thumbnail_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/white" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/network_3" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about specifying both the `layout_width` and `layout_height` to 120dp each? Like below

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/item_thumbnail_container"
 android:layout_width="120dp"
 android:layout_height="120dp"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:background="@color/black" >
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: oh,sorry my fault. not ImageView's android:layout_height, FrameLayout's android:layout_height.

i think, framelayout's height is 120dp,width is wrap, imageView's height and width both are match, then, image height will match to 120dp, and scale its width, at last framelayout will fit its width to the imageview.

Comment: Oh, no , it set FrameLayout's H&W fixed. 
But I hope that only the FrameLayout's high fixed,
width is followed by ImageView.